# Error while sending message in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to make a producer in Kafka

My Maven pom.xml is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Producer Code is

```
import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class KafkaProducer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zk.connect", "serverIp:2181");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
    Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);
    producer.send(new KeyedMessage<String, String>("TestTopic", "Message1"));
}
```

While executing this code, I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Missing required property 'metadata.broker.list'
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.getString(VerifiableProperties.scala:177)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:66)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:56)
at kafkaPOC.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:16)
```

**Can anyone please help me solve this exception.**

Thanks in Advance.!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `metadata.broker.list` property.

```
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "<Kafka broker IP address>:9092");
```